# FabricJS Styles not update after setOptions function has been applied

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

FabricJS Styles not update after **setOptions** function has been applied.
Basically, what I need is to get a style (for example FontSize) from styles when setOptions has been applied.

For my understanding, setOptions kind of updates a BLOCK style, not line style, but I need to get it in text line styles.

It's the same if I would need to get "RENDERED" styles of the text lines...

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(500);

var text = new fabric.Textbox('Hello world', {
  left: 50,
  top: 10,
  fontFamily: 'arial',
  fill: '#333',
  fontSize: 50
});

canvas.add(text);

const style = {
 fill: 'red'
};

text.setOptions(style)

canvas.renderAll();

text.on('changed', function(){
 console.log('___Expecting to get style here with RED text color___', this.styles);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/yjz6drL0/

Comment: while setting options it wont fire `changed` event.

Comment: So, where would you like the red to appear? the red text? all? or just some part?

Comment: Andrea... Doesn't really matter... In general, I want to get its "rendered" styles... Whatever is on the screen (Text Element) - transfer it to the style and return it... The reason is that its ForntSize (as an example) could be changed few times, so I need to, kind of, "preserve" previous values of  FontSize as well. So I was thinking about a way to be able to get its "Rendered Styles" based.

Answer (score 0):

So 'text:changed', or 'changed' is an event that fires at text input changes from the user.

There are no events that catch dev changes, since you place the code for them to happen, you should not need an event to find out they changed.

If you want to change to a particular style, you have to create a style object or use `setSelectionStyle`

So `text.setOptions` is a generic method for initialization that takes care of initializing gradients and patterns too. In this case it gets an object with the key fill, it has no clue it is a style.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(500);

var text = new fabric.Textbox('Hello world', {
  left: 50,
  top: 10,
  fontFamily: 'arial',
  fill: '#333',
  fontSize: 50
});

canvas.add(text);

var data = {
  0: {
    0: {
      fill: 'red'
    },
    1: {
      stroke: 'yellow'
    },
    2: {
      textDecoration: 'underline',
    },
    3: {
      textBackgroundColor: 'pink'
    },
    7: {
      fill: 'green'
    },
  }
}

// OR if you want to change the fill for all the text you can also do:

// text.setSelectionStyles({ fill: 'red' }, 0, text.text.lenght);

text.set('styles', data);

canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```